# Stuck on "downloading packages (0:03 remaining)"

Tags: system-installation, 20.04

So I just started installing ubuntu. I follow the installation guide and the "create a bootable usb" guide from ubuntu. Everything was working and I was installing it. Now it got to the step, downloading packages. Well it says it has 0:03 remaining. So I guess 3 min. Well it has been saying that for the last 2 hours. I saw that there was a skip button, but it does not work. I also noticed that the screen tips that keep scrolling stopped. Upon pressing the arrow that goes to the next tip, also does not work. The cursor is displaying a loading icon. I am not sure what to do. Is it just taking extremely long and is the installing time remaining nothing to go by, or is there something wrong? If yes what would the best steps of action be? If I search for this problem I only get results for already working Ubuntu systems.

Comment: Probably a network connection error. You can try to re-start the installation from the beginning.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Can I just shut the computer down and restart safely or is there another way I should go about doing that?

Comment: Personally I'd switch to a text terminal (ctrl+alt+f4 for example), and explore what the system was doing, if any errors conditions, what they are etc... You are a little vague on details, (Ubuntu Server using `subiquity` installer, Ubuntu Desktop using `ubiquity` etc) but that's what I'd do..

Comment: @guiverc I just downloaded the version 20.04 LTS desktop Ubuntu and followed the tutorial after that. I also did ctrl+alt+f4, and I just get a blinking line so I'm not sure what I should do to check for errors that would inform you what went wrong.

Comment: If you are not getting the "login:" prompt after you press Ctrl+Alt+F4, then probably the system is locked up. You can restart your computer and re-try a fresh installation. I am assuming that your computer's disk does not hold any previous operating system and you are doing a completely new Ubuntu installation by erasing anything that happen to exist on your disk.